# Aggregating rows with query in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set that looks something like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| category 1 | Team 1 |
| 1.category 1 | Team 1 |
| 2.category 2 | Team 1 |
| category 2 | Team 1 |
| category ３ | Team 1 |
| ３.category ３ | Team 1 |

I am trying to use query function with a pivot statement to calculate the occurrence of each category for team 1 (I have several other teams in the data set, but for simplicity I just wrote out my example with team 1). Unfortunately the naming of the categories are not consistent in the original data, and I cannot change them.

So I need a way to combine the results of the sum of category 1 and 1.category1, and so on.

How could I handle rewrite this to get the type of result as listed below?

| Category | Team 1 |
| --- | --- |
| category 1 | 2 |
| category 2 | 2 |
| category ３ | 2 |

The formula I have now is as following:

```
query('sheet1!A:B,"Select A, count(B) where B='Team 1' group by A pivot B label B 'Team 1'",1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(
LAMBDA(DATA,CATEGORY,
 LAMBDA(RESULT,
  LAMBDA(RESULT,
   IF(RESULT="",0,RESULT)
  )(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(RESULT,"&")),"|"),"SELECT Col1,SUM(Col3) GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 LABEL Col1'Category'",0))
 )(
  JOIN("&",
   BYROW(CATEGORY,LAMBDA(CAT,
    JOIN("&",CAT&"|"&BYROW(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(DATA,"SELECT COUNT(Col1) WHERE lower(Col1) CONTAINS'"&CAT&"' PIVOT Col2",0)),LAMBDA(ROW,JOIN("|",ROW))))
   ))
  )
 )
)({ASC($A$2:$B$7)},{"category 1";"category 2";"category 3"})
)
```

1. use `ASC()` to format all numbers-like values into number,
2. use `{}` to create the match conditions,
3. iterate the conditions with `BYROW()` and...
4. use `QUERY()` with `CONTAINS` to `COUNT` matches of the given conditions,
5. use `TRANSPOSE()` to turn the match results of each row sideway,
6. change the results into `string` with `JOIN()`, this helps to modify the row and column arrangment,
7. `SPLIT()` the data to create the correct array format we can use,
8. use `QUERY()` to `PIVOT` the `SUM` of the `COUNT` result as our final output.

---

Another approch works in a slightly different concept:

```
=ArrayFormula(
LAMBDA(DATA,CAT,
 LAMBDA(DATA,
  LAMBDA(COLA,COLB,
   LAMBDA(COLA,
    LAMBDA(RESULT,
     IF(RESULT="",0,RESULT)
    )(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({COLA,COLB},"SELECT Col2,COUNT(Col2) GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1 LABEL Col2'Category'",0)))
   )(REGEXEXTRACT(COLA,JOIN("|",CAT)))
  )(INDEX(DATA,,1),INDEX(DATA,,2))
 )(ASC(DATA))
)($A$2:$B$7,{"category 1","category 2","category 3"})
)
```

We can modify the Category column of the input data with `REGEXEXTRACT()` before sending it into query, which in this case, do make the formula looks a bit cleaner.

---

Inspired by @The God of Biscuits 's answer, we can now get rid of the `CAT` variable, which makes the formula more elastic to fit into your condition.

This `REGEXEXTRACT()` will extract Category value from the 1st 'category' match found to the end of the 1st 'number' after it, with any spacing in between the two value.

```
=ArrayFormula(
LAMBDA(DATA,
 LAMBDA(COLA,COLB,
  LAMBDA(RESULT,
   IF(RESULT="",0,RESULT)
  )(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({COLA,COLB},"SELECT Col2,COUNT(Col2) WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col2 PIVOT Col1 LABEL Col2'Category'",0)))
 )(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(INDEX(DATA,,1)),"((?:category)(?: +?)(?:[０-９]|[0-9])+)"),INDEX(DATA,,2))
)($A$2:$B)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the category names all have a similar format to those in your example (with extraneous data only at the beginning, followed by 'category N', and you don't care if zero counts per category are left blank then a more compact approach then the previous answer is (for any number of teams/categories):

```
=arrayformula(query({regexextract(A2:A,"category.+"),B2:B},"select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1 'Category'",0))
```

Comment: `regexextract` is good trick then `pivot`.

Comment: Your sulotion don't require to declare the category match condition, I think it is better than mine.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I was not specific enough in my example. Unfortunately, in the real data all categories have different names, with no common parts. But I will keep this in mind for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter with a count a like this:

```
=counta(filter(Sheet1!A:A,(Sheet1!A:A="category 1")+(Sheet1!A:A="1.category 1"),Sheet1!B:B="Team 1"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I need a formula that gives me a pivot array that looks just like the second table example I gave. there shouldnt be any manual input for either rows or columns, just the formula